# Working but maybe not optimal

Tags: python, optimization

So this is my second program in python, from what I've read here and some place else, globals aren't the best thing to use but for now this is where i'm at in my course so i would like you to not to comment on why globals are evil.

Right now the program is doing what it's supposed to do, my only concern is that it might be too long for nothing so i'm asking you guys to help me figure out where i could make it simpler.

Here it is:

```
import simplegui
import random
import math

#Globals, random guess and player's remaining guesses

num_range = 100
remaining_guesses = 7

# New game, range from 0 - 100 by default

def new_game():
    global num_range
    global remaining_guesses
    remaining_guesses = 7
    print "New game. Range is from 0 to 100"
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    print ""
    num_range = random.randrange(0, 101)
    return num_range

# Set game to a range of 0 - 100 
# after the according button is pressed
# Reset the remaining guesses to 7

def range100():
    global num_range
    global remaining_guesses
    remaining_guesses = 7
    print "New game. Range is from 0 to 100"
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    print ""
    num_range = random.randrange(0, 101)
    return num_range

# Set game to a range of 0 - 1000 
# after the according button is pressed
# Reset the remaining guesses to 10

def range1000():
    global num_range
    global remaining_guesses
    remaining_guesses = 10
    print "New game. Range is from 0 to 1000"
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    print ""
    num_range = random.randrange(0, 1001)
    return num_range

# Compare guess to random range
# Remove 1 to remaining guesses
# Display hint on the random range
# Restart the game if player is correct or out of guesses

def input_guess(guess):
    guess = float(guess)
    global remaining_guesses
    global num_range
    remaining_guesses -= 1
    print "Your guess was: %i" %(guess)
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    if (remaining_guesses == 0 and guess != num_range):
        print "The correct answer was %i" %(num_range)
        print "Let's try again!"
        print ""
        print ""
        new_game()
    elif (remaining_guesses == 0 and guess == num_range):
        print "Correct!"
        print ""
        print ""
        new_game() 
    elif guess > num_range:
        print "Try a lower number!"
    elif guess < num_range:
        print "Try a higher number!"
    else:
        print "Correct!"
        print ""
        print ""
        new_game() 
    print ""
    return guess, remaining_guesses

# Create & start frame

f = simplegui.create_frame("Guess the number", 200, 200)

f.add_button("Range is [0, 100]", range100, 200)
f.add_button("Range is [0, 1000]", range1000, 200)
f.add_input('My label', input_guess, 50)
f.start()

# Start a new game

new_game()
```

Comment: This belongs in the code review site.

Comment: how do i post on there^

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MalikBrahimi there is no such thing as "real programmers" but i guess you can say i'm a very bad programmer.

Simple GUI is required in the course i'm taking, which is obviously an introduction to python.

Comment: You taking that Coursera thing, right?

Comment: Well good luck, sorry that is all can do for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @rchang Whether or not this is on-topic on [so] has **nothing** to do with whether or not this is on-topic on [codereview.se].  You should only vote to close on [so] if it is off-topic on [so] (which as nothing to do with it possibly also being on-topic elsewhere).  Instead, perhaps you could flag for migration?

Comment: @nhgrif Fair enough, that does seem like the more appropriate approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def range(r=100, rg=7):
    global num_range
    global remaining_guesses
    remaining_guesses = rg
    print "New game. Range is from 0 to {}".format(r)
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    print ""
    num_range = random.randrange(0, r+1)
    return num_range
```

and replace `new_game()`, `range100()` and `range1000()` by `range()`, `range()` and `range(1000,10)` respectively.

Comment: why downvote? ... post a comment please.

Comment: i guess this is because i did not post in the right section and you still answered my questions, btw thank you for taking the time to answer.